# Static fields for types in Julia

Tags: julia

I'd like to have something of the form

```
type Foo
    a::Int
    b::Int = 5
    end
```

Where `Foo()` gives an instance of type `Foo` with `Foo.a` remaining unassigned and `Foo.b = 5`.

But the default implicit constructor only works when none of my fields are assigned, and thus since I want `Foo.b = 5` to be preassigned (and both static and final if possible), I have to define my own internal constructor, can anyone show me how to do this? I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by 'static and final'. If you mean "static" as in "is global, rather than having to do with an instance", don't put it in the type declaration at all. If you mean "final" as in "cannot have subtypes", that's the case for all concrete types in Julia.

Comment: @MikeGraham I mean static and final in the Java sense of the words.  By "static" I mean belonging to the type rather than having to do with an instance, however I'm not sure such a distinction exists for types (as opposed to classes), by "final" I just mean it cannot be changed.

Comment: If something does not belong to the instance, then don't put it in the type definition at all. Realize that in Julia you might use a module for things that in Java you might use a class. (If this global thing is mutable, be very leary.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I think I figured it out, I have to start with fields I want pre-defined, but wait to define them using `new()` in the internal constructor, and for fields I want to remain undefined, I can't give them a pre-defined type, here is the code:

```
type Foo
    b::Int
    a

    Foo() = new(5)
    end
```

Now `Foo()` gives `Foo(5, #undef)`.

Comment: There is no reason why you shouldn't give `a` an `::Int` annotation as well. If you want the field to be possibly empty, use `Nullable{Int}` instead of allowing it to be `#undef`.